# SMOTE on dataframe of arrays issues

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sliding-window, smote

I'm trying to attempt to SMOTE on a dataframe full of sliding windows here:

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjgeO.png)

I'm using imblearn's SMOTE() function on it. Without any manipulation, I'm getting an error that each cell must have a size 1 array. SMOTING individually by rows or exploding the dataframe and SMOTING on each window (same index) results in a ValueError because there is only one class in each SMOTE attempt. **How do I get around this problem of wanting to SMOTE an entire sliding window without aggregating them or getting dimensional errors by keeping it in the dataframe in the first picture?**

```
new_df_labels = X_with_labels.reset_index().apply(pd.Series.explode)
new_df = X_smoted.reset_index().apply(pd.Series.explode)
np.unique(new_df.index)

X_list = pd.DataFrame(columns = X_smoted.columns)
y_list = []

for j in np.unique(new_df.index):
    new_df1 = new_df[new_df.index == j]
    new_df_labels1 = new_df_labels[new_df_labels.index == j]
    X_smoted_1, y_smoted_1 = smot.fit_resample(new_df1, new_df_labels1['Activity'])
    X_list = X_list.append(X_smoted_1)
    y_list.append(y_smoted_1.ravel())
```

[Exploded DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z0s2.png)